# Is it bad practice to combine PHP and HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This may be a small question, but I haven't found any direct answer yet. Is it considered bad practice to use PHP alongside HTML? (using PHP foreach for example in combination of with HTML)

I have searched on Google and I didn't find a direct answer. Another example: What should I do when an user logs in on a website. Do I store the important information with $_SESSION (PHP) or should I store it with sessionStorage(Javascript)?

Comment: Most recommend separating your business logic, like MVC frameworks.  However, using PHP for templating is fine.  I'm not sure how you'd loop through results to print out a table row by row without using some type of loop.

Comment: Seems to me you are asking two totally different things here.... Not sure where you heard not to mix HTML and PHP. Maybe it is not mix business logic with output... Got to build dynamic HTML somehow.  Data storage, it depends....

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using PHP loops to generate repeating HTML; you'd have to copy-paste the content multiple times to accomplish this otherwise, and that goes against DRY principles. As for Storage, use what's appropriate. If your page uses only JS for logic, then maybe `sessionStorage` is correct.

Comment: Yes its bad practice to combine PHP and HTML. Use template engines like Smarty for View part of MVC. Also, regarding session question, you would need to ask different question. Only one question or relevant questions should be there per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) HTML and PHP go hand in hand, and unless you know one of the two languages ​​you have to use them together

2) you should save the information with the $ _SESSION of php and destroy them every time a user logs-out